# how to sort values with XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, xslt-2.0

I have an XML similar to this:

```
<Test>
  <grapes>
     <a>TypeA</a>
     <b>value1</b>
  </grapes>
  <oranges>
     <a>TypeB</a>
     <b>value2</b>
  </oranges>
  <apples>
    <a>TypeA</a>
     <b>value3</b>
  </apples>
</Test>
```

where the values are unique but the Type, might be the same.

I am trying to sort it so that the output is similar to this:

```
<group type="TypeA">
  <value v="value1" />
  <value v="value3" />
</group>
<group type="TypeB">
  <value v="value2" />
</group>
```

I am having a hard time making sure the groups are unique in the output and the values are in the right group.

How should my XSL be structured?

Comment: Since I didn't see grouping in the title, I'd just like to clarify: you want to group _and then_ sort?

Comment: Very useful question (and great answers). I agree title should be rephrased, since this is a common issue, and the answers would be of interest to many if they could better spot this question is theirs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XSLT 1.0 :

You start by creating unique groups for your types using the muenchian method. Google it to find out what it is. Then it's just a matter of iterating through them and printint out what you want, how you want it :

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:key name="types" match="a" use="text()"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<result>
  <xsl:for-each select="//a[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('types', text())[1])]">
    <group type="{current()/text()}">
      <xsl:for-each select="//a[text() = current()/text()]">
        <xsl:variable name="values" select="following-sibling::b | preceding-sibling::b"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="$values">
          <value v="{current()}"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </group>
  </xsl:for-each>
</result>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You will find that the output is identical to what you expect.

Comment: Make sure you understand what is written here. If you have any questions feel free to ask.

Comment: Can you explain what is happening here exactly?
//a[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('types', text())[1])]

Comment: Basically you generate unique id's for all a elements based on their text value and you then iterate through them.

Comment: Ahh ok, one more thing, why would this be needed:
<xsl:for-each select="following-sibling::b | preceding-sibling::b"> if you are already looping though each that match the group name.

Comment: Because once I had the groups I need to get all the siblings and iterate through them. In this case your siblings are named b but I didn't know that e.g. b will always follow a or vice-versa so this axis simply selects all b elements after and before the a element.

Answer (score 2):

**Here is a much simpler solution** (completely "push style", no `<xsl:for-each>`, no nesting, no `<xsl:variable>`, no `current()`, , no `//`, no axes):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:key name="kGoodsByType" match="/*/*" use="a"/>

 <xsl:template match=
  "/*/*[generate-id()
       =
        generate-id(key('kGoodsByType', a)[1])
       ]
  ">
     <group type="{a}">
       <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kGoodsByType', a)/b"/>
     </group>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="b">
  <value v="{.}"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*/* | text()" priority="-1"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<Test>
    <grapes>
        <a>TypeA</a>
        <b>value1</b>
    </grapes>
    <oranges>
        <a>TypeB</a>
        <b>value2</b>
    </oranges>
    <apples>
        <a>TypeA</a>
        <b>value3</b>
    </apples>
</Test>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<group type="TypeA">
   <value v="value1"/>
   <value v="value3"/>
</group>
<group type="TypeB">
   <value v="value2"/>
</group>
```

**Explanation**: **[Muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.xml)** of `/*/*` using as key the string values of their `a` children.

**II. XSLT 2.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:for-each-group select="*/a" group-by=".">
   <group type="{current-grouping-key()}">
     <xsl:sequence select="current-group()/../b"/>
   </group>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is performed on the same XML document (above), the same correct result is produced**:

```
<group type="TypeA">
   <b>value1</b>
   <b>value3</b>
</group>
<group type="TypeB">
   <b>value2</b>
</group>
```

**Explanation**:

1. `<xsl:for-each-group>`
2. `current-group()`
3. `current-grouping-key()`

Answer (score 0):

My proposal is slightly different from FailedDev's:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/Test">
    <root>
      <xsl:for-each select="*[a != following::a]">
        <xsl:sort select="a" data-type="text" />
        <group type="{a}">
          <xsl:for-each select="/Test/*[a = current()/a]">
            <xsl:sort select="b" data-type="text" />
            <value v="{b}" />
          </xsl:for-each>
        </group>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The outer

```
<xsl:for-each select="*[a != following::a]" />
```

select all unique types, ie. **TypeA** and **TypeB**.
The

```
<xsl:sort select="a" data-type="text" />
```

sorts these according to name, making sure **TypeA** will appear above **TypeB**.
The inner

```
<xsl:for-each select="/Test/*[a = current()/a]" />
```

selects a list of unique values for each type, ie. for **TypeA** the values **value1** and **value3** are extracted. Again, the resulting list is sorted to list **value1** before **value3**.

Comment: Quite wrong -- don't use the `!=` operator when one of the operands is a node-set. -1. Also, always run/test your proposed solution, before posting!

Comment: This is tested seems to work without problems.
Although I will agree your solution with Muenchian grouping is probably the way to go.

Comment: @_Mace: Your answer is wrong -- you were just lucky that it "works" on the provided XML document. Try it with this XML document and see that it produces *two groups* for "TypeA": `<Test>
  <grapes>
     <a>TypeA</a>
     <b>value1</b>
  </grapes>
  <oranges>
     <a>TypeB</a>
     <b>value2</b>
  </oranges>
  <apples>
    <a>TypeA</a>
     <b>value3</b>
  </apples>
  <peaches>
    <a>TypeB</a>
     <b>value4</b>
  </peaches>
</Test>`